# how to get data from ajax request in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am doing ajax request and passing this data

```
    $.ajax({
  url: "{{URL::to('match')}}/"+ id,
  type: 'PUT',
  // dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
  data: {
    match_id : id,
    start_time : newTime,
    competitionId: {{$cid}},
    _token:     '{{ csrf_token() }}'
  }
})
```

and in laravel trying to get this data as

```
dd($request->start_time);
```

but it is not working i am getting null

In chrome developer tools 
data with ajax request sent correctly this is one simple

```
match_id:1
start_time:03:00
competitionId:1
_token:9p8plPay7HLvJvMrTgxayEH74Ow6c2D1cli1yU01
```

all of this was working fine before I moved this site to a new server

have i missed any file ?

Comment: Try getting the parameters via $request->input - according to https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#retrieving-input that should work regardless of request method.

Comment: Check the network tab in your browser (Chrome).

Comment: I have used this method . I have also tried dd( $request->all()); but getting  this []

Comment: @theAlpha I have given above simple from network tab

Comment: @MuhammadAwais Can you show us your controller method in full, and relevant routes?

Comment: Route
Route::resource('/match', "MatchController");

http://pastebin.ca/3798572

Comment: check you php artisan route:list

Comment: here it is
 PUT|PATCH   | match/{match}   | match.update  |App\Http\Controllers\MatchController

Comment: check my answer

Comment: its should be match.update |App\Http\Controllers\MatchController@method

Comment: I am using resource Controller

Route::resource('/match', "MatchController");

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works fine after i changed type to Post and then added a field _method: PUT 
i.e

```
$.ajax({
      url: "{{URL::to('match')}}/"+ id,
      type: 'POST',
      // dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
      data: {
        _method: 'PUT',
        match_id : id,
        start_time : newTime,
        competitionId: {{$cid}},
        _token:     '{{ csrf_token() }}'
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

type php artisan route:list

check your route there for example your

Method = put

Uri = match/{match}

Name = match.update

Action = App\Http\Controllers\MatchController@**update** //your method

Route:

```
Route::resource('/match', 'MatchController');
```

this is your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'match/'+ id, //this is your uri
    type: 'PUT', //this is your method
    data: { match_id:id, start_time:newTime },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){

    }
});
```

Your Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $match_id)
{
   if(request()->ajax()){
      $match = Match::find($match_id);
      $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
         'start_time'=>'required',
      ]);

      if($validator->passes()) 
      {
        $match->start_time = $request->start_time;
        $match->save();

        return response()->json(['msg'=>'Updated Successfully', 'success'=>true]);
      }
      return response()->json(['msg'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using resource Controller Route::resource('/match', "MatchController");

Comment: same I am using Route::resource('/trademark', 'TrademarksController');

Comment: If you are using resource route you should have App\Http\Controllers\MatchController@method after your controller your method

Comment: so what i am doing wrong ?
my route is correct that's why i am getting null or empty array on changing code on server side

Comment: dear in ajax type is mentioned to specify method type and i have put there

Comment: Did you try in your method controller to return $request->all();  if you get any response?

Comment: try return true in your method update if u will get response

Comment: return "reaching ?";
and getting 
reaching ?

Comment: i am getting id

Comment: sorry i am getting id which is passed by url not from ajax data portion

Comment: here is screenshot of ajax request submission 

https://ibb.co/ffv5T5

and i am passing data correctly 
but not getting any data in laravel 
as on executing
$request->all() i am getting [] so code that you have edited does not effect

Comment: that's weird if you are in your method but not getting result in $request->all(); 

do you have if(request()->ajax()){    } wrapping your controller code?

Comment: i have just tried by wrapping code in if(request()->ajax()){ }
as it was ajax request so if block executed successfully

Comment: still not getting any result?

Comment: no 
data that i have passed in ajax data portion is not coming in laravel